# How to prescale a frame using ffmpeg and H.265

Tags: c, ffmpeg, scale, h.265

I want to decode video frames with the H.265 coded (`AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC`)
I use the following code:

```
AVCodec *hevcCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC);
AVCodecContext *avctx  = avcodec_alloc_context3(hevcCodec);
avcodec_open2(avctx, hevcCodec, 0);
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.data = myDataPtr;
pkt.size = myDataSize;
int got_frame = 0;
avcodec_send_packet(avctx, &pkt);
if (avcodec_receive_frame(avctx, frame) >=0 ) {
        got_frame = 1;
        ...
}
```

This works fine, I got my YUV frame and can process it further (like converting to RGB or scaling, etc.)
However, I would like to somehow tell the ffmpeg library, to scale the `AVFrame` while decoding (a scale factor of a power of 2 would be sufficient).
I don't want to scale after converting to RGB or use `swscale` or anything. I have to decode a lot of frames and need a smaller resolution.

Is it possible to give the `AVCodecContext` some hints to scale the frames?
(I tried setting `avctx.width` and `avctx.height`, but this did not help)

Comment: 1240 rep and no formatting skills :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, decode and scale can not be combined into a single, faster step. You must fully decode then scale. You can scale and convert to RGB as a single step with `swscale`

Comment: Okay, this is sad, but I think you're right. I will do some benchmarks with `swscale`.

Comment: If scaling is not possible while decoding then what does this value do int AVCodecContext::lowres ? The definition found from https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/avcodec_8h_source.html says 
#if FF_API_LOWRES
    /**
     * low resolution decoding, 1-> 1/2 size, 2->1/4 size
     * - encoding: unused
     * - decoding: Set by user.      */
       int lowres;
 #endif 

The line "low resolution decoding, 1-> 1/2 size, 2->1/4 size" suggests its possible to decode while scaling. But setting this is not working properly. I'm trying to figure this out too.

Comment: That is supported only by a VERY limited number of codecs. You need to call `av_codec_get_max_lowres` (or check the source code for .max_lowres) to see if the codec supports it. Most do not.